# What is the difference between sequence container and precedence constraint?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

If I don't connect tasks using precedence constraint then they are running parallel in sequence container. Could anyone suggest me on this?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/sequence-container)?

Answer (score 1):

## Sequence Container

*Based on this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/sequence-container):*

> The Sequence container defines a control flow that is a subset of the package control flow. Sequence containers group the package into multiple separate control flows, each containing one or more tasks and containers that run within the overall package control flow.

## Precedence Constraints

*Based on this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/precedence-constraints):*

> Precedence constraints link executables, containers, and tasks in packages in a control flow, and specify conditions that determine whether executables run

---

## Comparison

There is no comparison between ***"Sequence Container"*** and ***"Precedence Constraints"***, based on your needs, you have to choose if you have to place Tasks in Sequence Containers or to link them using Precedence Constraints.

*Note: if it is about running single Tasks in parallel there is no need for sequence container just add Tasks to the control flow without linking them and they will run in parallel.*